# Most efficient way to implement switching images on web page

Tags: html, css

I need to add an animation made of frames in .jpg format to a html page.
There are different ways one can achieve that via javascript:

- changing the `display` property of several `img` elements within the same container
- changing the `src` attribute of a single `img` element
- changing the `background-image` property of a container element

In terms of performance (loading time, fluidity), are these methods equivalent?

(Due to requirements, I cannot create a video separately and use the `video` tag.)

Comment: I dislike the second option, it is not semantic in my opinion. The two other approaches are identical performance-wise, imo. It all depends on your implementation. Use lazy loading and performance will be identical. However, what is the goal of the image? What will it represent? An image that is relevant and discussed, or just some background prettiness?

Comment: it's a series of photos from different angles of a product. Swiping on it would create an animated-rotation effect. Definitely relevant. Also, the resolution is quite high.

Answer (score 0):

Empirical evidence says that

> changing the `background-image` property of a container element

causes flickering.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, make sure your images are compressed well. I can advise [TinyJPG](https://tinyjpg.com/).

Because you said in a comment that you want to make some sort of gallery, it seems better to have all images as image in HTML and show/hide when necessary. Semantically this is clearer, because you can then give each image its own descriptive alt tag.

To solve loading issues: first load the image that you'll show first, and then append the others with JS. By doing so, you ensure that enough bandwidth is available for a fast download of the first image. When the DOM is ready, the JS is executed and the other images are added (hidden) and downloaded in the background.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const imgs = [{
        alt: "Mustang rear view",
        src: "http://st.motortrend.com/uploads/sites/10/2015/09/2014-ford-mustang-rear-view.jpg"
      },
      {
        alt: "Mustang side view",
        src: "https://www.mustang6g.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/SideStang.jpg"
      },
      {
        alt: "Mustang top view",
        src: "http://st.motortrend.com/uploads/sites/5/2012/01/1965-Ford-Shelby-GT350-Mustang-top-view.jpg"
      }
    ],
    container = $(".container");

  $.each(imgs, function(index, img) {
    const imgHTML = $("<img>").attr(img).hide();
    container.append(imgHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.euroncap.com/media/26111/2017_ford_mustang_uncrashed-image-gallery.jpg" alt="Front view of Ford Mustang">
</div>
```